# The Cayley Representation Theorem.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutations

This theorem states that "Any group is isomorphic to a subgroup of a group permutations." 
I only ask if someone could provide a simple example so that i can fully understand this theorem.

Comment: Do you know the proof of the theorem?

Comment: @Seth yes, and it's a pretty long proof.

Comment: But the basic idea is very simple, just that every group acts on itself by left multiplication which is a permutation.  This is what gives the isomorphism.  So this gives you all the examples you could want.

Comment: Pretty long? The version I know is essentially one line. Let the group act on itself by left multiplication.

Comment: @AlexBecker , if you don't mind, providing your version of the proof.

Comment: That is my version of the proof. It makes the theorem obvious if you understand $S_n$ as acting in a universal way on sets with $n$ elements.

Comment: This isn't a proof, but it's a good way to feel its "truthiness". Think about the Cayley table (multiplication table). Each row has all the elements, and exactly one of them. It's kind of like sudoku. And you can get each row from the identity one by multiplication. So you can think of multiplying as shuffling the elements around. (Formalizing it follows this intuition, as Alex is saying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for a simple example, so here is one: Consider the group $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$. This is a finite abelien group under addition of order $n$.

Let
$$
\phi: \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow S_n
$$
given by
$$
\phi([1]) = (1\; 2\; 3\; \dots \; n ).
$$
So
$$
\phi([m]) = (1\; 2\; 3\; \dots \; n )^m.
$$
Then $\phi$ is a injective. Note that $S_n$ is a multiplicative group.

Note that all you had to do here was to find an element of order $n$ in $S_n$. In fact, the above example is easily extended to embedding any cyclic group in some permutation group (since any cyclic group is isomorphic to a $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n$).

Answer (score 1):

For example, say you have a finite Abelian group which is a product of cyclic groups of orders $q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n$. Then let $N = \sum_j q_j$ and consider the permutation group $S_N$. For each $q_j$, choose a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ of size $q_j$ where all the subsets are disjoint. Then consider the subgroup generated by a set of cycles, where you have one cycle over each disjoint subset of characters that you picked. The subgroup generated by these cycles will be isomorphic to your Abelian group.